# Mathematical Biology Jobs/Prospects?

Tags: theoretical-biology, biotechnology, topology

I'm a junior math major starting to take his first courses in Algebra, Analysis, Topology, Nonlinear and Partial Differential Equations, etc.

I am just considering my career options at this point and somebody told be biotech/biology could have some interesting work. So I have come here to hear some advice if that is okay! Is there anything highly mathematical about the search for anti-aging or achieving the whole "biologically immortal" thing? I just don't know about any of this stuff so please inform me :)

PS: I also know Prob/Stats at a decently advanced level. So there's that too. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Off course you can! Here are career paths for you as per my limited knowledge:

1. **BioStats**

There are lot of applications in this domain. For example in Microarray Gene Expression or Proteomics analysis (for example, [this paper](http://www.pnas.org/content/97/1/262.full)).

2. **Bioinformatics**

Sequence alignments use common techniques like Dynamic Programming, Probabilistic or Heuristic methods, etc.

3. **Computational Biology**

There are lot of applications like Lagrangian and Eulerian Mechanics (Computational Anatomy), Computational Phylogenetics (Computational Evolutionary Biology), etc.

4. **Systems Biology** - In Systems Biology, you can have applications in:

1-) Probability and Hypothesis Testing - usually used to find [associations between genes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_association) (Ref: S. Krawetz (ed.), Bioinformatics for Systems Biology, DOI 10.1007/978-1-59745-440-7_8, Chapter 8)

2-) Stochastic Modelling of Biological Patterns - ODEs,PDEs (applied to lot of problems), [Markov Chains](http://www.biostat.wisc.edu/bmi576/lectures/markov-chains.pdf), [HMM](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2766791/), [PSSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_weight_matrix) are common mathematical implementations in this domain.

3-) Population Genetics - uses Statistical models (for example [Genetic Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_distance)), exponential equations (for example, [Cumulative Effect of Mutation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8380576))

P.S: Here are some tools you might be interested in:

1-) [Bioconductor](https://www.bioconductor.org/) - one of the main reasons why R is preferred language by BioStatisticians.

2-) [BioPython](http://biopython.org/)

Wish you best of luck with your career!